# What happens when we use loop instead of while(true) with scala actors?

Tags: scala, actor

What's the difference of using loop instead of while(true) while using receive with actors. Loop seems to work much faster, but why, and what's going on under the bonnet?

Is there anything bad to use loop instead of while(true)?

More about context. I'm doing performance tests within simple ping/pong code. And I'm using receive.

This is the Ping class:

```
class ReceivePing(
        count : Int,
        pong : Actor
       ) extends Actor {def act() {
var pingsLeft = count - 1
pong ! Start
pong ! ReceivePing
while(true) {
  receive {
    case ReceivePong =>
      if (pingsLeft % 10000 == 0)
        Console.println("ReceivePing: pong")
      if (pingsLeft > 0) {
        pong ! ReceivePing
        pingsLeft -= 1
      } else {
        Console.println("ReceivePing: stop")
        pong ! Stop
        exit()
      }
  }
}}}
```

instead of while(true) it performs better with loop.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `loop` releases the thread to other tasks, while `while` doesn't. So, if you are using many actors, the use of `loop` makes then more efficient. On the other hand, a single actor using `while` and `receive` is much faster than one using `loop` and `react` (or, for that matter, `loop` and `receive`).

Comment: So does it mean receive or react doesn't have any impact on the thread. "while" and "loop" keywords are controlling the threads.

Comment: @Zerdush No, `loop` and `react` have an impact on the thread -- they both release it. Neither `while` nor `receive` release the thread.

Answer (score 4):

The `while`/`receive` loop [blocks a thread](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/242), whereas the `loop`/`react` construct doesn't. This means the first construct needs one thread per actor, which quickly becomes slow.

According to [Haller and Odersky 2006](http://lamp.epfl.ch/~phaller/doc/haller06jmlc.pdf),

> An actor that waits in a receive
>   statement is not represented by a
>   blocked thread but by a closure that
>   captures the rest of the actor's
>   computation. The closure is executed
>   once a message is sent to the actor
>   that matches one of the message
>   patterns specied in the receive.
>   **The execution of the closure is "piggy-backed" on the thread of the sender.**
>   If the receiving closure
>   terminates, control is returned to the
>   sender as if a procedure returns. If
>   the receiving closure blocks in a
>   second receive, control is returned to
>   the sender by throwing a special
>   exception that unwinds the receiver's
>   call stack.

(Apparently they later changed the behavior of `receive` and renamed the old `receive` to `react`.)

Comment: But I'm talking about loop with receive not with react. What is the difference between while/receive and loop/receive? Is there any problem using loop/receive? It seems faster.